# problem with the initial route in createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, jsx

In my `BottomTabNavigator`, I have an overview tab. When I click it, it bring the overview tab's initial route. From here, I can click to see more details. This will routes to a different screen. Let's call it (B)

My issue is if I am in this Route/page (B) inside my Overview Tab then I click on a different tab and I go back to Overview it show me Route/page (B) however I want it to display Route/page (A) if I change a tab and come back to it.

How can I do that?

This is my OverviewStack.js

```
import OverviewStack from "./overviewStack";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
.
.
.
const OverviewStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...OverviewRoutes,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Overview",
    resetOnBlur: true,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      ...SharedHeader(navigation),
    }),
  }
);
```

tabNavigator.js

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
.
.
.

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Overview: {
      resetOnBlur: true,
      screen: OverviewStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",
      },
    },
    Averages: {
      resetOnBlur: true,
      screen: TrackStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Track",
      },
    },
```

Comment: Hey @GHOST, have a look on the answer. I think it addresses the concern in the question. If so, please mark it correct, so that the bounty is awarded. If you do not do so, the automated bounty system will award only half the bounty, which, I think, would be unfair.

Answer (score 5):

`resetOnBlur` is not available in the latest (version 5.x) React Navigation. It was deprecated, and a new similar functioning option `unmountOnBlur` was introduced.

Here, I have created an Expo Snack for you: https://snack.expo.io/@nishantatthatmate/vigorous-peanut

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Link } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function OverviewStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="OverviewScreen" component={OverviewScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="DetailScreen" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function OverviewScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Overview!</Text>
      <Link to="/DetailScreen" style={{color:'blue'}}>Go to Detail</Link>
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Detail!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Overview" component={OverviewStack} options={{unmountOnBlur: true}} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

If you notice, I am setting the options for the screen(s) that we want to unmount on blur with `unmountOnBlur: true`.

One possibly undesired side effect of this is, if you are on the DetailScreen under Overview tab, and you happen to tap the Overview tab again, it brings you back to OverviewScreen (because DetailScreen was popped out). This may or may not be your expected user experience. But, there are another way to customize behavior by listening to various events on `Tab.Screen` as described below.

If you want to get fancy, you can add a listener on `Tab.Screen` and do more involved stuff, see here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#listeners-prop-on-screen

```jsx
<Tab.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
    tabPress: e => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();

      // Do something with the `navigation` object
      navigation.navigate('AnotherPlace');
    },
    blur: () => {
      // Do things here
    },
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `resetOnBlur` into `createBottomTabNavigator` Options like this [DOCS](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/bottom-tab-navigator/#bottomtabnavigatorconfig)

```js
import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const TabBarComponent = (props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} />;

const TabScreens = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    // other screens
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: (props) => (
      <TabBarComponent {...props} style={{ borderTopColor: '#605F60' }} />
    ),
    resetOnBlur:true //add here
  }
);
```

Comment: same thing it did not work. It didn't work, when I to my main screen then pull a view on that screen and try to change tab and comeback it stays in the last screen instead of defaulting to the main.

Comment: can you add a reproducible example to your GitHub and share it with me so I can fix this issue for you

Comment: Muhammad Numan, Thank you so much for helping. I have updated the code to reflect my files.